# Puppeteer - scroll down within a div (multiple scrollbars on one site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

I'm trying to scroll down at this site:

[link](https://www.betsson.com/en/sportsbook/football/italy/italy-serie-a)

The page is dynamically loaded, so I'll need to scroll down on the page to make it load. But the problem is that it's multiple scrollbars within certain divs.

I would like to scroll down within this div `.obg-m-sportsbook-layout-fluid-container`.

Does anyone have some tips? For full screen scrolling I've always used `puppeteer-auto-scroll`, but doesn't seem to work on selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to scroll down inside the div? If so, then you can use the CSS property

```
scroll-behaviour: smooth
```

plus the

```
window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

function of JS.

ShadowLp174

[Edit]

Scroll the last loaded element into view using `element.scrollIntoView({options});` 
On your side it worked for me with this random example inside the div: \

```
document.querySelector(".obg-m-events-master-detail-header-title").scrollIntoView({ left: 0, block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
```

I scrolled a bit down before, so it was loaded but it should work with other elements too.

Comment: How can I connect this to the correct div? This will just scroll the full screen page?

Comment: for your purposes: try to scroll to the last loaded element inside the div... Here: i tried this and it scrolled to the random element inside the div
`document.querySelector(".obg-m-events-master-detail-header-title").scrollIntoView({ left: 0, block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion scrolling down on all these markets under 'All' tab? [link](https://www.betsson.com/en/sportsbook/football/england/england-efl-championship?eventId=f-8NmUcDBTVkmS6mKkBlCdTw). Click event and it'll pop up all markets, click the 'All', and I need to scroll all the way down. But it's no selectors to pick so it seems hard to use scrollIntoView.. @ShadowLp174

Comment: Can't you get the elements through the container as children? You could loop through the children using the for loop